# How to retrieve a Map from a Map in dart efficiently?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map returned  from json.decode of type `Map<String,dynamic>`

The dynamic part contains another map which I want to have in a separate variable. I managed to do that in the following way:

```
Map<DateTime, List<DayOffDto>> mapToReturn = Map();

    Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(
      response.body,
      reviver: _reviver,
    );
    if (responseBody == null) {
      throw NoDataServerException();
    }
    responseBody.entries.forEach((element) {
     Map map = element.value;
      //map.values;
      map.entries.forEach((element2) {
        mapToReturn[element2.key] = element2.value;
      });
    });
//mapToReturn  contains now the extracted map from responseBody
```

and the reviver function just does some converting for me

```
_reviver(dynamic key, dynamic value) {
    if (key != null && value is Map && (key as String).contains("-")) {
      var object = value;

      final DayOffDto dayOffDto = DayOffDto.fromFirebase(
          key_firebase: key as String,
          parsedJson: value,
          rota: rotaParam,
          chosenYear: yearParam);
      DateTime datetime = Helper.getDateTimeFromDayNumber(
        dayOffDto.dayNumber,
        dayOffDto.year,
      );
      Map<DateTime, List<DayOffDto>> internalMap = LinkedHashMap();
      internalMap[datetime] = [dayOffDto];
      return internalMap;
    }

    return value;}
```

I do not think it is the best way of extracting . Any idea for the optimized code?
  `responseBody.values`  returns `Iterable<V>`

so when I do 
`mapToReturn =  responseBody.values`  i am getting an error

Comment: maybe responseBody.values does what you want?

Comment: this tutorial might give u some hint: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/managing-data-in-dart-flutter-8f267f0f1d84

Comment: responseBody.values returns Iterable<V>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `Map` can be hard sometimes. I would like to tell you that there is something as easy as `mapToReturn =  responseBody.values`, but as of today, there is not (that I could find).

However, I can give you one small block of code that does the same as your first code block.

As you are not using the `keys` of your first map, instead of `responseBody.entries` you should use `responseBody.values`. So the code block would end up like this:

```
responseBody.values.forEach((value) {
  return value is Map<DateTime, List<DayOffDto>>
      ? mapToReturn.addAll(value)
      : null;
});
```

And if you are completely sure about the value `Type` (you should, as you are using a `reviver`) you can make it only one line of code.

```
responseBody.values.forEach((value) => mapToReturn.addAll(value));
```

I hope this can help you!